# Lebesgue Measure in $\Bbb{R}^k$ is invariant under isometries

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I'm studying Lebesgue Measure. I have a problem on proving that Lebesgue Measure in $\Bbb{R}^k$ is invariant under isometries

Here is my work so far.
Let $T$ $\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k$ is an isometries
We know that if A is Lebesgue measurable then T(A) is an isometries

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is measurable Lebesgue then $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists (\Delta^n)_n \subset \mathbb{R}^k , A \subset (\Delta^n)_n$ 
and     $\mu(A)+\epsilon > \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\Delta^n| = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |T(\Delta^n)| >\mu(T(A)) $

After that, we need to prove that $\mu(T(A)) \ge \mu (A)$.

Let's choose $T'=T^{-1}$, $A'=T(A)$ we got $\mu(T(A)) \ge \mu (A)$.

---

The problem is $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |T(\Delta^n)| >\mu(T(A))$ is true if we got $T(\Delta^n)$ are rectangle. But if T is rotation, $T(\Delta^n)$ aren't rectangles so I am stuck here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show that the measure of a rotated rectangle is equal to that of its non-rotated counterpart. Then the measure of an arbitrary subset $A$ is limit to a countable union of non-rotated rectangles (ie each of those rectangles are the products of intervals). Now a rotated $T(A)$ is limit to a countable union of rotated rectangles, each of which is limit in measure to a union of ordinary rectangles. It should be more formal, but I haven't done measure theory in a long time.

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to prove that $\int f \circ T d\mu=\int f d\mu$ for, say. continuous functions with compact support. This equation follows easily be change of variable formula since the Jacobian is $1$.

Comment: I believe that if you check Folland's change of variables theorem you will have your answer

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Will it help me to solve my problem ? I think it is a different way to approach the statement

Comment: I think it comes as a corollary